# RegEx to clean VISA merchant names (remove random strings)

Tags: regex, data-cleaning

I am trying to develop a ReGex (.Net flavor), which I can use to clean VISA merchant names.

Examples:

```
Norton *AP1223506209  --> Norton *AP
Norton *AP1223511428

EUROWINGS   VYJD6J_123001  --> EUROWINGS
EUROWINGS   W6PDFI_125626

AER LINGUCB22QKM2  --> AER LINGUCB
AER LINGUCB248L2W

AIR FRANCE  JWNCSC  --> AIR FRANCE
AIR FRANCE  K8L7TT

PAYPAL *AIRBNB  HMQXBW  --> PAYPAL *AIRBNB
PAYPAL *AIRBNB  HMQXNZ

SAS         1174565172360  --> SAS
SAS         1174565172368
```

I would like to keep the first "name" part, but remove the second "gibberish" part.

The following Regex works for Norton and Air Lingu as well as for Eurowings and Air France, if they contain numbers in the gibberish part. It totally fails for PAYPAL *AIRBNB and other strings, that don't contain any numbers in the gibberish part, and also for SAS, probably because the name is too short / there are too many spaces:
Search:

```
([A-z *-]{2,50}[A-z]{2,50})(.{0,3}([0-9-]{0,3}[A-z *+.#-/]{0,3}){1,10})
```

Replace:

```
$1
```

Is there any way to make this work for gibberish parts that don't contain numbers? I have something like this in mind, but don't manage to create an according RegEx:

**Group 1 (to keep)**

- Must contain consonants and vowels
- Can contain **few** numbers, spaces or punctuation signs (e.g.: "7x7: Taxi Service")

**Group 2 (to be removed)**

- Consists of sequences of numbers, letters and optional punctuation signs
- OR: consists of consonants, only
- OR: consists of numbers, only

Thanks for any help and best regards

Pesche

**Edit:**
If I add more examples, Lindens solution still works quite well, but does not recognize all of the examples or in some cases too much of the string. I tried to adjust it, but with my lacking skills didn't quite succeed:

https://regex101.com/r/7y9zGl/4

The following problems remain:

- with a length of 6 for the last \w, longer patterns would not be matched in full length (e.g. after easyjet and after EMP Merchan). Increasing it, however, causes other strings to be truncated (e.g. AER LINGU, potentially also HOTELS.COM if > 12 was used).
- The merchant names after PAYPAL * and GOOGLE * should not be deleted, as they are true merchant names. I tried to exclude strings containing GOOGLE * with a negative lookbehind, but it does not seem to work like that.
- Whereas the merchant name after PAYPAL * should generally remain, in some cases it is followed by gibberish, e.g. PAYPAL *AIRBNB  HMQXBW. If the negative lookbehind worked, those cases would no longer be cleaned.
- if the merchant name is not followed by gibberish, part of the name itself may be deleted (e.g. EMP Merchan)

As the full list of merchant names is long and versatile, the approach to detect "gibberish" should be as generic as possible (i.e. not rely on a certain length of the gibberish part). Hence my original, now slightly modified "pattern":

- Consists of sequences of numbers, letters and optional punctuation signs
- OR: consists non or very few vowels (EASYJET     000ESJ5TWN -> the gibberish contains only one vowel, EASYJET 3 of them; PAYPAL *NITSCHKE -> NITSCHKE should not be matched, it contains 2 vowels)
- OR: consists of numbers, only

Is such a thing even possible? The goal is to use SQL to clean the merchant names. If necessary, this can be done in several run throughs (for different kind of patterns).

Thx again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated regex based on extended sample and desired results:

```
[\s*<]+\d+$|[\s*<]+(?![A-Z]{6}.*)\w*\d[\w>]*$|\d{6,}$|[\s*<]+[A-Z]{6}$|(?![A-Z]+$)(?<=[A-Z])\w{6}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7y9zGl/8)

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly, thx a lot! I'll try to adapt it to the other cases (which I did not show in the examples). If I don't manage, I might ask for your expertise again :)

Comment: Sorry, I removed the solution as I indeed need some more help, looking at new examples (see the edit part in my original post). But you were already very close! Thank you :)

Comment: Can you comment in all the provided examples what the expected result is (the regex link).

Comment: Yes, of course: https://regex101.com/r/7y9zGl/6
You may need to remove the comments, as they interfere with the regex.

The goal is to extract what identifies a merchant, and discard the rest. In most of the cases it doesn't matter if the last * is included or not.

Comment: Hi @PescheHelfer, it's gotten a bit long, but this is the best I can do.

Comment: Amazing, looks very promising! Thanks a ton! Now, I will try to figure out how this piece of genius works :)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot validate as I'm only on my phone, but can you try something like this?

```
^([0-9A-Za-z\*][ ]{0-2})
```

Take all the numbers, the letters (capital and minor) the star and max 2 spaces from the beginning of the line.

Please check the () but I guess the idea is here.

Sorry, it seems wrong when there is no double space.

You want to take all the char until 2 spaces or 2 numbers according to your examples.

```
.* {2}|.*[0-9]{2}
```

Is it better?

Regards, 
Thomas

Comment: @linden2015 solution looks better :)

Comment: Thx, Thomas! The second version almost works, but matches a bit too much of the strings. I'll keep it in mind to find a solution that works for most merchants.